# Ocaml's sprintf doesn't work with %a format specifier

Tags: ocaml, format-specifiers

It seems that `sprintf` does not allow `%a` in its format specifier. Is this right? If so, why is it like this, and is there a workaround?

**Example.** I have a long and complicated datatype:

```
type t = Foo | Baz
```

I have a pretty-printer for this type, that sends a string representation of its values to an arbitrary `out_channel`:

```
let pp_t oc = function
  | Foo -> fprintf oc "Foo"
  | Baz -> fprintf oc "Baz"
```

If I then write

```
let _ = printf "%a=%d" pp_t Foo 2
```

or

```
let _ = eprintf "%a=%d" pp_t Foo 2
```

then everything works fine -- the message "Foo=2" ends up on my stdout or my stderr as expected. But if I write

```
let s = sprintf "%a=%d" pp_t Foo 2
```

then I get a compilation error, complaining that the argument `pp_t` has type `out_channel -> t -> unit` but an expression was expected of type `unit -> 'a -> string`.

Is it simply not possible to use `%a` inside a format specifier for `sprintf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get away with specific datatypes showing up in your formatting functions you should always use the `Format` module and devise pretty printers for your types that have the signature `val pp_t : Format.formatter -> t -> unit`; this is also the signature the toplevel asks for to install custom printers with `#install_printer` for your datatypes.

Equipped with such a function you can then simply use [`Format.asprintf`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALasprintf) with `"%a"`.

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

Use the `Format` module for the pretty printing and the `Format.asprintf` function instead of `sprintf` for constructing strings (I usually just do `open Format` at the beginning of a file).

### Long answer

It is possible to use the `%a` conversion specification with `sprintf`. However, the required function has a type that is different from what is required for `Printf.fprintf` and `Printf.printf`.

All pretty-printers (functions that satisfy a type of a value, that is required by the  `%a` conversion) encode the type of output in their types. So for different families of `printf` functions you need to use different pretty-printing functions.

In the case of the `Format` module pretty-printers, you need a function of type `formatter -> 'a -> unit`. This is the type that is also required by the top-level and the debugger, and it is also a most common type of a pretty-printing function (libraries such as Core, as well as many other libraries, provide pretty-printers that satisfy this signature). The `Format` module also provides the `asprintf` function, that, unlike the `sprintf` function, plays nice with the `%a` conversion (i.e., it has the same `formatter -> 'a -> unit` type).

In the case of `Printf.printf` the type of a pretty-printer should be `out_channel -> 'a -> unit`. This type is much less versatile and thus is much less popular than the Format's one. Very few libraries provide one.

Finally, the `Printf.sprintf` function requires a printer of type `unit -> 'a -> string`. Usually, the only way to get such pretty printer is to write it manually (sometimes using `Printf.asprintf`). In your case it would be:

```
let pp_t () = function
  | Foo -> "Foo"
  | Baz -> "Baz"
```